# How to read json file that has javascript language in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
[{
    "title" : "제품 소재 (섬유의 조성 또는 혼용률을 백분율로 표시, 기능성인 경우 성적서 또는 허가서) 예시) 폴리에스터-75%",
    "detail" : [
      {
        "code" : "0101_0",
        "title" : "제품 소재",
        "html" : $sce.trustAsHtml("<input type='text' class='form-control' ng-model='details.value'>"),
        "value" : ""
      },
      {
        "code" : "0101_1",
        "title" : "기능성 여부",
        "html" : $sce.trustAsHtml("<label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='prod' ng-value='Y' ng-model='details.value'>대상 상품</label>" +
        "<label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='prod' ng-value='N' ng-model='details.value'>대상 아님</label>"),
        "value" : ""
      }]}]
```

I have Json File above and I am trying to read this json file in angular.js.

```
$http.get('/views/online/product/json/01.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.prod_info = data;
}).catch(function (err){
  console.log(err)
})
```

but it shows error beacause json file has javascript language which is '+' as well as $sce.trustAsHtml method etc.

How can I read json file that has javascript language in angular?

Comment: That is not a JSON file. That is a JavaScript file. Pretty much the only thing you can do is read it in and evaluate it. (`eval` is evil but no choice here, if that's really what you want to do.) It might be a better idea to rethink what you are doing though.

Comment: Why are you using `$sce.trustAsHtml()` in JSON file?

Comment: I use ng-bind-html in angular.js.
I made that json source(source) in angular.js at first.
and then cut json source to new json file.

but json file is not js file. so this error comes up.

Comment: dude pass ONLY the html in the file an as you need it use the $sce.trustAsHtml() function to bind it.  Also I am with Amadan, you might want to rethink your application strategy.

Comment: Thanks your answer I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON in `/views/online/product/json/01.json` is invalid.

The JSON needs to be valid in order to be loaded by AngularJS (default without response interceptor), you can check your JSON validity using https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Please correct to following:

```
[{
    "title": "제품 소재...",
    "detail": [{
        "code": "0101_0",
        "title": "제품 소재",
        "html": "<input type='text' class='form-control' ng-model='details.value'>",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "code": "0101_1",
        "title": "기능성 여부",
        "html": "<label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='prod' ng-value='Y' ng-model='details.value'>대상 상품</label><label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='prod' ng-value='N' ng-model='details.value'>대상 아님</label>",
        "value": ""
    }]
}]
```